# make antd table row only visible when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have simple antd table where is columns 'State','Title' and three rows, i dont know how to display:none specific row by default and make it visible by clicking a button for example at the moment when user goes to the table by default there is three rows but i want to set row 'value === OrderState.Delivered' to 'display:hidden' by default, but when user clicks button 'Delivered' then it should be visible and when user clicks 'All states' button then everything should be visible except that same 'value === OrderState.Delivered'. Here is my code, you can try it :
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-surf-t9eh3?file=/src/Test.js:1345-1355

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I made to your code

- by default filter eventsData to not show the Delivered one

  ```
  const [filteredEventsData, setFilteredEventsData] = useState(
    eventsData.filter((f) => f.key !== "Delivered")
  );
  ```
- in the filterData function, filter out delivered even when All states is clicked

  ```
  function filterData(filter) {
    if (filter) {
      setFilteredEventsData(eventsData.filter((f) => f.key === filter));
    } else {
      setFilteredEventsData(eventsData.filter((f) => f.key !== "Delivered"));
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: i implemented it in my real code(using typescript) and it is working except, by default it is still showing 'Delivered' am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: did you implement 
`const [filteredEventsData, setFilteredEventsData] = useState(
  eventsData.filter((f) => f.key !== "Delivered")
); `
 Maybe check the case. It's supposed to be filtering the "delivered" out

Comment: i'm getting 'eventsData' like this  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch once
    api.cargoApi
      .apiCargoAccountingOrdGet(request)
      .then((res: React.SetStateAction<CargoOrdDto[] | undefined>) => {
        setFilteredEventsData(res);
      });
  }, [api.cargoApi]);

Comment: should i put this '  eventsData.filter((f) => f.key !== "Delivered")
' into that useffect somehow ?

Comment: Yes you can add the filter here: `setFilteredEventsData(res);`

Comment: setFilteredEventsData(res?.filter((f:any) => f.state !== "Delivered")) this is not working

Comment: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'CargoOrderDto[] | ((prevState: CargoOrderDto[] | undefined) => CargoOrderDto[] | undefined)'.
  Property 'filter' does not exist on type '(prevState: CargoOrderDto[] | undefined) => CargoOrderDto[] | undefined'.ts(2339)

Comment: Since I dont have your exact code I can't help you further. The main concept is that you filter "delivered" out before adding it to "filteredEventsData" array in the state. You can also do that by writing a custom function setFilteredEventsData() which takes in events data, filters it out, and then adds it to state. Try any method to filter it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231700/discussion-between-shubham-periwal-and-walee).